# Uninstall Dependant Pear Packages

Tags: command-line-interface, pear

How do I uninstall these pear packages when they depend each other?

```
sh-3.2# ./pear uninstall saucelabs/PHPUnit_Selenium
saucelabs/PHPUnit_Selenium (version >= 1.1.6) is required by installed package saucelabs/PHPUnit" saucelabs/PHPUnit_Selenium cannot be uninstalled, other installed packages depend on this package
```

and:

```
sh-3.2# ./pear uninstall saucelabs/PHPUnit
saucelabs/PHPUnit (version >= 3.5.24) is required by installed package saucelabs/PHPUnit_Selenium" saucelabs/PHPUnit cannot be  uninstalled, other installed packages depend on this package
```

Also tried this:

```
sh-3.2# ./pear uninstall -f saucelabs/PHPUnit 
Console_Getopt: unrecognized option -- f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to uninstall them both at the same time?

```
sh-3.2# ./pear uninstall saucelabs/PHPUnit saucelabs/PHPUnit_Selenium
```